# Django, не сохраняется форма

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

не сохраняется форма

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    video = models.FileField()
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from .models import video

class videoform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = video
        fields = ('name', 'video')
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import videoform
# Create your views here.

def video(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = videoform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = videoform()

    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

`base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Во-первых, покажите html-код формы

Comment: Во-вторых, вы забыли использовать request.FILES а значит файл в форму не попадёт

Comment: Добавил html код

Comment: Отсутствие атрибута `enctype="multipart/form-data"` у формы также помешает загрузке файла

Comment: Спасибо, помогло